# Include/delete a checkbox automatically when a column is not empty

Tags: google-apps-script

I need to have a new checkbox automatically created in column 2 every time that column 1 is populated. Any helper, please?

Answer (score 2):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if(e.range.getSheet().getName()!='SheetName')return;
  if(e.range.columnStart==1 && e.value && !e.oldValue) {
    e.range.offset(0,1).insertCheckboxes();
  }
}
```